# Novel about a man who could enter the minds of animals

Tags: story-identification, magic

I read a book a few years back, and would love to read it again. The overall plot I don't remember much of, but the main character could enter the minds of animals. It was a huge taboo to do so, and those that had the skill were usually killed. The boy was apprenticed to the master of hounds at the local castle, and the master of hounds knew the boy's secret. The danger was that those able to do this usually became more beast than man.

Does anyone know what this might be?

Similar to wargs from Game of Thrones.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the book you are looking for is the [Assassins Apprentice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassin%27s_Apprentice) by Robin Hobb.
It is the start of a trilogy about Fitz,

> who possesses what is known as "The Wit", an ancient and distrusted
>   magic which allows him to bond telepathically with animals.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. Now I remember exactly when I read it.